# need to access current_app in a async method

Tags: python, flask, ansible

I have setup an application in Flask that calls an ansible runner and i want to register the status of the runner in a db, in order to not change the nginx web server timeout i decided to use the ansible_runner in async(it is an option of the runner itself)

```
r.run_async(inventory=inventory, playbook=playbook_path, extravars=vars, status_handler=checkstatus)
```

status_handler calls a routine every time the status of the operation changes

```
def checkstatus(data, runner_config):
print(data)
global stato
stato = data['status']
global runner
runner = data['runner_ident']
db=get_db()
if stato=="successful" or stato=="failed" or stato=="timeout":
    db.execute(
            'INSERT INTO tasks (runner, status)'
            ' VALUES (?, ?)',
            (runner, stato)
        )
    db.commit()
```

the issue is that i can't access the db because it is bound to the current_app with g in a blueprint and i can't seem to be able to access it in the async task

any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to [Manually Push an App Context](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/appcontext/#manually-push-a-context)?

Comment: Yes, but in the blueprint i don't have an app object and if i try to call it the app name becomes <appname>.<blueprintname> becoming an entire new application afaik